# Absurd values to main(int argc, char** argv)

Tags: windows, msvcrt

I had on old C++ project starting a Console-application.
With a breakpoint in `main(int argc, char** argv)` started `program.exe -debug`.
According to the debugger *argc* became 32 and the strings in *argv* had weird random-like values.
When execution continued *access violation* occurred, since the strings in *argv* pointed to invalid values.

What can be causing this?

Comment: Did you print the value of `argc` within main to `stdout` to see if it also reported 32?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The linker had wrong *Entry Point* set.
For a normal console application this should be `mainCRTStartup` (the debugger shows `__tmainCRTStartup`).

Having an invalid entry point caused main to look at what "happended" to be in the stack.
Posting this since it was not trivial to find.

Comment: Thanks for following up and posting this arcane bit of knowledge.

Comment: i doubt so. if the linker didn't find `__tmainCRTStartup` it will complain, but apparently it didn't and continue to link the project. i suspect that `char** argv` is the cause of the crash (a non writable buffer). try `char * argv[]`.